# Error in lambda function in Java while handling list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have recently switched from C++ to Java and facing tough times to deal with the syntax and lambda functions. So there is one method which got updated. I am confused editing the code correspondingly.

So initially getCostChangeDtl() used to return data of type CostChangeDtl but now the same method returns a list of CostChangeDtl. So I made some changes accordingly still facing some issues.

## Before

```
costChangeDetails.forEach(
            costChangeDetail -> changeDtls.addAll(costChangeDetail.getItems().stream().map(item -> {
                CostChangeDtl despCostChangeDtl = getCostChangeDtl(ccd, costChangeDetail, item,
                    metrics);
                        
                            if (despCostChangeDtl.getItemID() == null)
                            {
                                String consumerGtin = item.item.getConsumerDetails().getConsumerGtin();
                                missingSkuGtins.add(
                                        format("%s | %s ", consumerGtin, costChangeDetail.getLocation().getId()));
                            }
                        
                        return despCostChangeDtl;
                    }).filter(despCostChangeDtl -> despCostChangeDtl.getItemID() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

## After

```
costChangeDetails.forEach(
            costChangeDetail -> changeDtls.addAll(costChangeDetail.getItems().stream().map(item -> {
                List<CostChangeDtl> despCostChangeDtl = getCostChangeDtl(ccd, costChangeDetail, item,
                    metrics);
                        for (CostChangeDtl costChangeDtl : despCostChangeDtl) {
                            if (costChangeDtl.getItemID() == null)
                            {
                                String consumerGtin = item.item.getConsumerDetails().getConsumerGtin();
                                missingSkuGtins.add(
                                        format("%s | %s ", consumerGtin, costChangeDetail.getLocation().getId()));
                            }
                        }
                        return despCostChangeDtl;
                    }).filter(despCostChangeDtl -> despCostChangeDtl.getItemID() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Now I am getting an error in despCostChangeDtl.getItemID() as expected since it is despCostChangeDtl is now a list.
How to fix this particular issue?

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: Hi, I did not run the code so did not any error msg as such. I was getting error from the IDE itself. in the .filter() despCostChangeDtl is a list. so despCostChangeDtl.getItems() is invalid we need to loop through. I am facing issue while fixing this part.

Comment: Have you tried changing `despCostChangeDtl` to literally anything else inside your call to `filter()`, and prepending a call to `stream()` before you call `filter()`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry for being such a dumb.

Comment: I think you will have to split this into 2 steps. Collect all your `List<CostChangeDtl>` in step 1. Then apply filter over all the items in step 2. I will post an answer separately because it difficult to write it here.

Comment: `stream().filter(costChangeDtl -> costChangeDtl.getItemID() != null).collect(Collectors.toList())))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despCostChangeDtl from an object to a list, so you should flatmap after map.
[image]

Comment: After map opt, stream was Stream<List<CostChangeDtl>>. Use flatMap(List::Stream) change the stream to Stream<CostChangeDtl>.

Comment: That seems to have resolved the error at least it is not giving red marks in the IDE